# Filter array records

Tags: javascript, angularjs

.js

```
"rpsCommonWord": [
    {
        "addressWeightPct": "60",
        "charSubstituteWeightPct": "15",
        "nameWeightPct": "40",
        "oIdNumber": "21",
        "shortWordMinLthWeightPct": "100",
        "substituteWeightPct": "5",        
        "wordName": "Word 3"
    },
    {
        "addressWeightPct": "60",
        "charSubstituteWeightPct": "15",
        "nameWeightPct": "40",
        "oIdNumber": "21",
        "shortWordMinLthWeightPct": "100",
        "substituteWeightPct": "5",        
        "wordName": "abc 3"
    },
    {
        "addressWeightPct": "60",
        "charSubstituteWeightPct": "15",
        "nameWeightPct": "50",
        "oIdNumber": "21",
        "shortWordMinLthWeightPct": "100",
        "substituteWeightPct": `enter code here`"5",        
        "wordName": "Wordefd 3"
    }
];

$scope.onClickGo = function() { 
     //
};
```

.html

```
<strong><font color="#660099" face="Arial" size="1">wordName : </font></strong>
<strong><font color="#660099" face="Arial" size="1"><input name="wordName" type="text" value=""></font></strong>
<strong><font color="#660099" face="Arial" size="1">nameWeightpct : </font></strong>
<strong><font color="#660099" face="Arial" size="1"><input name="nameWeightpct" type="text" value=""></font></strong>
```

What I needed is, I want to search the records which "wordName" is "Word" or "WO". and the "nameWeightpct" is 40. It is just like "Like%" query in mysql. But Now I want to do it in frontend only. I have webservice which has all records but I want to filter array which has the records exactly or similar like entered value.

Comment: You'll need to loop on your data and implement such feature yourself then. Simple.

Comment: What have you tried and what isn't working in that attempt?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Answer (score 2):

You can create two variables to accept the search value for "wordName" and "nameWeightpct" and use filter provided by Angular.

Here is a sample code:

```
<div ng-init="friends = [{name:'John', phone:'555-1276'},
                     {name:'Mary', phone:'800-BIG-MARY'},
                     {name:'Mike', phone:'555-4321'},
                     {name:'Adam', phone:'555-5678'},
                     {name:'Julie', phone:'555-8765'},
                     {name:'Juliette', phone:'555-5678'}]"></div>

<label>Search Name: <input ng-model="searchName"></label>
<label>Search Phone: <input ng-model="searchPhone"></label>
<table id="searchTextResults">
  <tr><th>Name</th><th>Phone</th></tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="friend in friends | filter:searchName | filter: searchPhone">
   <td>{{friend.name}}</td>
   <td>{{friend.phone}}</td>
</tr>
</table>
```